# Python installer: "0x80070642 - User cancelled installation"

Tags: python, windows-7, installation, failed-installation

Whenever I try to install Python 3.6.3 (32-bit) to my Windows 7 laptop at work, the installer fails with the following error.

> 0x80070642 - User cancelled installation

This error consistently occurs half-way through the installation while installing "Python 3.6.3 Standard Library (32-bit)", as indicated by Python's progress bar turning red in the taskbar icon.

[Looking at the installer log](https://gist.github.com/Stevoisiak/b140b8408d4075fc4ad88bd30762b86a#file-python-3-6-3-32-bit-_20171023114548-log-L443-L447), I noticed a few entries which report `Failed to secure cache path:`, but searching these errors hasn't provided any additional details.

```
Error 0x80070005: Failed to secure cache path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\
Error 0x80070005: Failed to secure cache directory: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\
Error 0x80070005: Failed to get cached path for package with cache id: {C093353B-F9EE-4A06-923D-C1B340B82886}v3.6.6119.0
Error 0x80070005: Failed to cache payload: launcher_AllUsers
Failed to cache payload: launcher_AllUsers from working path: C:\Users\SVASCE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{973D88A7-E2AD-4A3C-AA24-79C5637B217A}\launcher_AllUsers, error: 0x80070005.
```

Comment: This will be better handled on the bugs.python.org issue tracker. The Windows installer for 3.5+ is almost entirely the work of only one Python core developer. He can at least take a look and see if maybe it's a problem with the installer or if information about the failure can be improved in the logs. `ERROR_INSTALL_USEREXIT` (0x0642) is probably just from the bundled installer canceling because of the `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` (0x0005) failure.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I was able to resolve the error by **unchecking '*Install launcher for all users*'**. Once unchecked, the installer worked as expected without any issue.

[image: Installer with "install launcher for all users" unchecked]

Presumably there was an issue with folder permissions, since this was on a managed work machine.

Comment: You are awesome. Thank you so much, I've been trying to do this installation on my workstation for 20 work hours! thanks!

Comment: The above answer did not work for me. I right clicked the setup and run it as administrator and then it worked!

Comment: This also works for Windows 10 and python 3.11 except the box label is a little different.  I ran as admin but not sure if it's needed.